# "Ещё (не) плохо" Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, наречия

*Это еще (не) плохо!*

Как писать здесь частицу "не" с наречием "плохо": слитно или раздельно? Влияет ли на это наречие "ещё"?

Comment: Без контекста дать краткий ответ не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны **оба варианта**, и это зависит от контекста.

**Вариант 1.**  ***Это еще неплохо!***

Такая **оценочная запись** наиболее вероятна при отсутствии сравнения или противопоставления.
Об этом можно  судить по примерам из Нацкорпуса, причем наречие ***еще*** оказывает влияние на частотность написаний:

(1) ***Это неплохо*** (210 примеров)

И через минуту: ― Как хорошо, что Пушкин этого не видит. ― Да, ― сказал я, ― это неплохо.  [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)] 1.  Это не плохо (50 примеров)

(2) **Это не плохо** (50 примеров)

Ну, растянется на несколько лет, ничего, это не плохо. [Александр Солженицын,1990]
Сама по себе такая способность ― это не плохо…
Это не плохо. Не лезет с глупостями, значит ― не будет раздражать… [В. Г. Галактионова, 2004]

(3) ***Это еще неплохо*** (3 примера)

В 182-й школе уроки пения проходят… в читальне. Это еще неплохо. Бывает, что и в гимнастических залах, коридорах. [И. Вершинина, 1956]

(4) ***Это еще не плохо*** (нет примеров).

**Вариант 2.  ***Это еще не плохо!*****

Можно представить такую запись: *Мы плохо живем? **Это еще не плохо!** Другие хуже живут.*

Здесь задана тема, а потом следует отрицание и сравнение.

**Дополнительное пояснение темы**

1. **Градация признака**

Многие качественные прилагательные и наречия имеют ряд **с градацией признака**, который выглядит так: *Хорошо – неплохо (почти хорошо) – не плохо (средняя оценка) – нехорошо (почти плохо) – плохо.*

Таким образом, форма написания НЕ дает представление **о степени признака**. Поэтому раздельное написание НЕ возможно и в утвердительных предложениях, а не только в отрицательных (при противопоставлении).

2. **Влияние наречия** ***еще***

Это наречие интересно с разных точек зрения. По мнению этимологов, определить его происхождение затруднительно – скорее всего, оно получено контаминацией разных основ. Но в современном языке оно имеет два основных значения: (1) добавление, повтор и (2) изменение признака в каких-либо пределах. Нас будет интересовать именно второе значение.

И вот добавление наречия ***еще*** к нашему градационному ряду упрощает решение задачи. Это можно видеть по количеству примеров в Нацкорпусе.

Средняя оценка (***еще не плохо***) встречается значительно реже, поэтому для сочетания «еще не плохо» обычно требуется **сравнение или противопоставление.**